# AssertJ: assertThatCode() vs assertThatThrownBy()

Tags: java, assertj

What is the difference between `assertThatCode(…).isInstanceOf(…)` and `assertThatThrownBy(…).isInstanceOf(…)`?

Both seem to work the same, to the point where `assertThatThrownBy()` allows you to chain `doesNotThrowAnyException()` too (which is a bit funny).

Comment: From the documentation of [`assertThatCode`](https://javadoc.io/static/org.assertj/assertj-core/3.25.2/org/assertj/core/api/Assertions.html#assertThatCode(org.assertj.core.api.ThrowableAssert.ThrowingCallable)): "_The main difference with assertThatThrownBy(ThrowingCallable) is that this method does not fail if no exception was thrown_".

Comment: @Slaw but I can still chain `doesNotThrowAnyException()`, can't I?

Comment: Yes, because both return `AbstractThrowableAssert`. That doesn't change the fact that `assertThatCode` and `assertThatThrownBy` have different semantics.

Comment: @Slaw by "different semantics" you simply mean the methods are named differently, don't you?

Comment: @Slaw to recap, `assertThatThrownBy()` *throws* if the lambda doesn't, and `assertThatCode()` *doesn't* throw under the same circumstances – is that correct (assuming we don't chain anything to them)?

Comment: By "different semantics", I mean that the two methods convey different meanings/intentions. If you use `assertThatCode`, then you are testing code that either may or may not be expected to throw an exception, depending on other conditions/context. If you use `assertThatThrownBy` , then you are testing code that is definitely expected to throw an exception.